# Inheritated hover "Mouseleave" not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have an inherited event on hover that looks like this:

```
$('#menu').on("hover", '#menu li', function() {    
//mouse over LI and look for A element for transition
$(this).find('img')
    .animate( { opacity:1 }, 200)
});
```

It works for all the inheritated elements, but I can't make the "mouseleave" event to inherit. If I add:

```
    $('#menu').on("hover", '#menu li', function() {    
    //mouse over LI and look for A element for transition
    $(this).find('img')
        .animate( { opacity:1 }, 200)
},
function() {
    $(this).find('img')
        .animate( { opacity:0.5 }, 200)
});
```

It doesn't work. How it works for the hover onleave event??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#menu").on('mouseenter','#menu li', function(){

    $(this).find('img')
        .animate( { opacity:1 }, 200)
     })
.on('mouseleave','#menu li', function(){
$(this).find('img')
        .animate( { opacity:0.5 }, 200) 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

`hover` is no typical javascript event, you have to split your binding in `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event.

```
$('#menu').on("mouseenter", '#menu li', function() {    
    //mouse over LI and look for A element for transition
    $(this).find('img').animate( { opacity:1 }, 200)
});

$('#menu').on("mouseleave", '#menu li', function() {
    $(this).find('img').animate( { opacity:0.5 }, 200)
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu').on("mouseover", '#menu li', function() {    
    alert('mouse entered');
});

$('#menu').on("mouseleave", '#menu li', function() {    
   alert('mouse left');
});
```